# How can I reference a section by number in org-mode export?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I'm working in org-mode and trying to generate a link to reference a section by its number, not its title.

```
* Section One
:PROPERTIES:
:CUSTOM_ID: sec:one
:END:

* Section Two
#+label: sec:two

I can reference Section One with  [[#sec:one]] and [[#sec:one][Section One]],
but I can't get the actual section number (1) to resolve.
```

I want to see

```
As you can see in Section 1
```

By writing something like

```
As you can see in Section [[sec:one]],
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I use *dedicated targets* for this:

```
* Section One
  <<sec:one>>

* Section Two
  <<sec:two>>

I can reference Section One with  [[sec:one]] and [[sec:one][Section One]],
but I can get the actual section number (1) to resolve.
```

This works as expected; see [the orgmode documentation on internal links](http://orgmode.org/org.html#Internal-links) for reference.

Comment: Hey Tom, when I try this the dedicated targets seem to show up in the output as <<sec:one>> etc.

Comment: Also, the line numbers don't resolve in latex export unless I do something like (setq org-export-latex-hyperref-format "\\ref{%s}").

Comment: Strange -- which version of org-mode are you using? I use 8.0.2, emacs 24. I'm checking my setup tomorrow for variables, but the org 8 documentation suggests this should work as is without special settings.

Comment: Ah, I'm on 7.9.4. I'll upgrade and check back.

Comment: On org <8.0, you can # out the <<target>> so the target is invisible but you can still link to it.

Comment: This is a weird solution: looking at the resulting latex, each annotated section now has two `\labels{}`

Answer (score 11):

Tom Regner's approach works, however, you don't have to use dedicated target, you can still use custom_id link, but **without** a description. Like this:

```
* Section One
:PROPERTIES:
:CUSTOM_ID: sec:one
:END:

* Section Two
You can reference Section One with [[#sec:one]] but NOT
[[#sec:one][Section One]], i.e., the link without description
will get you the actual section number (1).
```

Answer (score 8):

You can refer to sections by name:

```
* Section One

* Section Two

* Links
  This is a number link: [[Section One]]
  This is a textual link: [[Section One][Some text for the link]]
```

Here's the LaTeX output:

```
\section{Section One}
\label{sec:orgheadline1}

\section{Section Two}
\label{sec:orgheadline2}

\section{Links}
\label{sec:orgheadline3}
This is a number link: \ref{sec:orgheadline1}
This is a textual link: \hyperref[sec:orgheadline1]{Some text for the link}
```

Comment: If I compile the output latex file, everything is fine. If I use org export to produce the pdf, the references left as `???`.

Comment: Verified 03 Jun 2017 this solution is working with Emacs 25.1.1 and Org 9.0.6, and brilliantly easy.

Comment: In a living text, or having made a mistake, this has the downside that you have to change the section heading everywhere, if that need arises -- using dedicated targets or a custom_id as per @York s answers separates the link to the section from its title, making changes easier.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR:**
Use package `org-ref`.
Use internal links to label sections like `<<sec:section-name>>`
Use name for images, tables and source-codes, like `#+name: fig:my-fig`
Use command `M-x org-ref-insert-ref-link` to insert an internal link

**Details**

If you use Org-Ref ([usage link here](https://kitchingroup.cheme.cmu.edu/blog/2014/05/13/Using-org-ref-for-citations-and-references/)) which I highly recommend for technical writing, and also for good referencing practices, there's a user-friendly interface to manage internal references ([internal links](https://orgmode.org/manual/Internal-Links.html)).

Use the internal links format `<<link-name>>, and` #+name: another-name`format to create labels, and use key-sequence`M-x org-ref-insert-ref-link`to insert a link using a`completing-read` interface, which depending upon your setting may be augmented by Icicles, Ido, Helm, Company and so forth.

For example, in the following case:

```
* Section with labels
<<sec:sec-w-labels>>

[...] My story here [...]

#+name: fig:my-screenshot
file:my-screenshot.png

* Section with links
I can refer to the section with labels (see \S <I>)
containing an explanatory figure here (see Fig. <I>)
```

When my cursor is at either of the positions marked `<I>`, using a command `M-x org-ref-insert-ref-link`, which I have bound to `C-c C-x )`, the emacs shows me a list of completion candidates of all the internal links, which in this case are namely, `sec:sec-w-labels` and `fig:my-screenshot`.

Upon completion, the section should look like this, having `ref:` links:

```
* Section with links
I can refer to the section with labels (see \S
ref:sec:sec-w-labels) containing an explanatory figure
here (see Fig. ref:fig:my-screenshot)
```

To install, insert the following into your [Emacs init-file](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html) and restart. Or to just try, insert the following into your `*Scratch*` buffer and do `C-M-x`.

```lisp
;; Org Ref
(use-package org-ref
  :ensure t
  :after ob-http
  :hook (org-mode . ref-link-keymap)
  :config

  (defun ref-link-keymap ()
      (define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-x )")
        #'org-ref-insert-ref-link)))
```

**Limitation**

The `ref:` links export as just another link with same text and href values using all exporters. So in case of HTML export the link is presented something like:

```html
<a href="sec:bfm">sec:bfm</a>
```

In case of Latex, the compiler translates this internal link to section numbers.