# In org-mode, how to export internal links?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

In org-mode, I have a document that contains internal links, i.e. there are links in this format...

```
For more info, see [[*First%20heading][First heading]]
```

...that link to section headings:

```
* First heading
```

These links do not appear in my exported files, either in HTML or tex/PDF. Is there an org-mode setting that controls this?

Comment: Works for me (Org version 7.9.3f with Emacs version 24.3.1). Could you retry starting from `emacs -q`?

Comment: When I relaunch Emacs without customizations, it defaults to org 6.33 and yes it works. However, I'm running org 8.2.4.

Answer (score 3):

While it would be great to export header-links, (and it seems to have worked in versions prior 8.0), as a workaround you can do as [the manual](http://orgmode.org/manual/Internal-links.html) recommends and use either *dedicated targets*, as in

> ```
> - one item
> - <<target>>another item
> Here we refer to item [[target]].
> ```

or the `CUSTOM_ID`-property, [as in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16346622/how-can-i-reference-a-section-by-number-in-org-mode-export)

> ```
> * Section One
> :PROPERTIES:
> :CUSTOM_ID: sec:one
> :END:
>
> * Section Two
> You can reference Section One with [[#sec:one]] but NOT
> [[#sec:one][Section One]], i.e., the link without description
> will get you the actual section number (1).
> ```

(second example from [How can I reference a section by number in org-mode export?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16346622/how-can-i-reference-a-section-by-number-in-org-mode-export)).

Seems like using `* link_name` is a fallback solution:

> If none of the above succeeds, Org will search for a headline that is exactly the link text but may also include a TODO keyword and tags.